# Assigning positions to students using MySQL and PHP

Tags: mysql

I have a database that hold student scores, I have record for individual scores and total. The problem is calculating student position.

Sample table:

[image: sample table]

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: It's unusual to store averages in a database record - don't you calculate that from individual exams/subjects per student?

Comment: Either way, it is hard to know what you are asking here. Is the table for students? What is your algorithm for calculating student position? Are you wanting to achieve this with an `UPDATE` command?

Comment: The position is being calculate from the total mark, and I want to achieve this with an UPDATE command

Answer (score 0):

You question isn’t clearly defining your problem and you didn’t even share any code either. What I understood is you have all the students in the database and their position is "nil" by default. And you want to add position to the records according to the total marks.

I'll give you high level idea of what you can do. Select all the students sorted in ascending order of their total marks. Iterate through all and update the records with the iteration number.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not care about equivalent totals, you can get student position without using an update by doing something similar to the following:

```
SELECT student_name, total, @rownum := @rownum + 1 as position from tbl_web_users cross join (select @rownum := 0) as t order by total desc
```

Comment: I do care about equivalent total and will like to use the update command to update the records back to the table.